# Logstash docker image - No logstash-plugin?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, logstash

I have deployed LogStash on kubernetes using the latest image (logstash:8.8.1) and now I would like to install some plugins.
I understand that I would need to use the 'logstash-plugin' tool, whis should be located in the bin directory. But in my case there is no logstash-plugin in the bin directory.

Is there another tool that I can use?

Comment: The bin directory here is relative to logstash, which is likely /usr/share/logstash/bin. It may be different depending what you have deployed. Current version is 8.9 and not 8.1. documentation is here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/dir-layout.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/docker.html

Comment: Thank you, the problem was a wrong volume mapping.